# Multi-file upload for salesforce.com community (portal) users (VF preferred)

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, portal, multifile-uploader

I am looking for a solution to allow portal community users to upload multiple files simultaneously to an account. The community portal does not support App Exchange solutions designed for regular internal salesforce accounts.

I am wondering if somebody can help me write a VisualForce page that I would embed in the page layout.

Answer (score 0):

This two link will help you achieve your goal.
[uploading-an-attachment-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/28/uploading-an-attachment-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller/)

[upload-file-as-attachment-to-record](http://www.forcetree.com/2011/02/upload-file-as-attachment-to-record.html)